# How to Create a Bordered Area in WPF That Has a Background Image and Changeable Text

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've been learning some coding and have received some great pointers here, so I thought I'd ask about my current endeavor.

I'm currently experimenting with a WPF app and would like to try to create something like this (pardon the color scheme... I just threw this together):

[image: Inventory Items]

The desired outcome is:

1. Have a bordered area
2. The bordered area needs a background image
3. Programmatically changeable progress bar
4. Static text in various areas
5. Programmatically changeable text in various areas

I have no idea where to even begin on creating something like this.  I'm thinking of it from the perspective of a graphics editor like Paint.Net where I'd create layers for each element.  This may be the wrong way of thinking, but that's where I'm at.

Please remember I'm a novice, so you'll want to provide the "patiently explaining to a child who suffered head trauma" explanation.

Thanks!

Comment: UserControl would be a good starting point. It has its own XAML where you could add all those things. A WPF book would also be worth reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I have made a small sample.

[image]

Here are the XAML codes:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF3CFF00" BorderThickness="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100,100,0,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Pictures/circuit-1242111.jpg"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <TextBox Margin="20,10,20,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Text="103/250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"></TextBox>
            <ProgressBar Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="10"></ProgressBar>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8A8A8A" Opacity="0.85"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Text="Circuits"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF3CFF00" BorderThickness="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100,100,0,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Pictures/circuit-1242111.jpg"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <TextBox Margin="20,10,20,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Text="12/300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"></TextBox>
            <ProgressBar Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="10"></ProgressBar>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8A8A8A" Opacity="0.85"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Text="Switches"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF3CFF00" BorderThickness="5,5,5,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100,100,0,0">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Pictures/circuit-1242111.jpg"/>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <TextBox Margin="20,10,20,0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="{x:Null}" Text="347/500" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"></TextBox>
            <ProgressBar Margin="0,10,0,0" Height="10"></ProgressBar>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF8A8A8A" Opacity="0.85"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" Text="Resistors"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the background picture I used:

[image]

Comment: That looks fantastic.  Thank you so much.  I will experiment with WrapPanel and Grid controls, too.

Comment: Thanks again for supplying this.  I've been taking a WPF course on Udemy and have a much better understanding of your sample.  It's crazy how flexible WPF is compared to the old Windows Forms.